# Run Front-end and backend within single Docker container

Tags: docker, vue.js, go

I understand that it's best practice to always separate your front-end and your backend code. I have a Vue js application and a Golang server to do some business logic and I need them to be one unit that I can run from a single container. Any tips would be appreciated?

Thank you very much

Comment: Yes you can do it. We use to do that for our testing environments by using http://supervisord.org/ as the main process and which in turn used to launch rest of the processes. You can alternatively use `pm2`, `systemd` or any other process manager. You can even use raw background processes via a shell script (not recommended though)

Comment: Yes supervisord is the way to go. just some additional tips from my experience: 1. be sure to redirect the subprocess stdout and stderr to the main process stdout/err, 2. if your orchestration/mgmt handles restarting, make sure the start retries is set to 0, you dont want 2 levels of auto-restarts/timeouts.

Comment: I took a quick look at supervisord. It looks incredible for my use case. Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [multi-stage Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) to ensure you only copy the assets you need. Using a `scratch` image also cuts down on your image footprint significantly

The following multi-stage build, for example, builds a VueJS into a `dist` directory & a single Go binary and copies these to a minimal `scratch` image:

```
# go build
FROM golang:1.16.3 AS go-build

WORKDIR /
COPY    backend backend
RUN     CGO_ENABLED=0 go build

# node build
FROM node:15.13.0 AS node-build

WORKDIR /
COPY frontend frontend
RUN \
    npm i && \
    npm run build

#
# final stage:
#
FROM scratch

COPY --from=go-build \
    /backend/rest-server \
    /app/rest-server

COPY --from=node-build \
    /frontend/dist \
    /app/dist/

CMD ["/app/rest-server"]
```

In the above example, your REST service would not only serve your backend APIs - but also serve the static VueJS frontend assets built in the `/app/dist` directory:

```
h.Handle(
    "/",
    http.StripPrefix(
        "/",
        http.FileServer(
            http.Dir(conf.StaticDir), // e.g. VueJS's "/app/dist"
        ),
    ),
)
```

Comment: Building it this way is a good option. Thank you very much