# Trouble running a docker container for react-app where package.json is in a subfolder

Tags: reactjs, docker, dockerfile, create-react-app

I am trying to create a dockerfile for a project that has the following folder structure:

```
HDWD-project
|_ client
|    |_ package.json
|_ server
     |_ package.json
```

Client is a react-app and I am just working with this at the moment, before including server which is the backend.

I am having real trouble figuring out the logic of the dockerfile and have googled furiouly for the last two days. All the examples are too easy.

I just can't seem to get react-app to start in the container, and get varying error messages. But I need to know the dockerfile is fine before I proceed.

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR HDWD-project
COPY ./client/package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN cd client
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Going forward I have a script that can start both the server and the client, but I'm just trying to get my head around docker and getting the client frontend to run fine.

Would anyone be able to correct me on where the issue in this config is and explain it?

Comment: You can build the docker image in the client folder where its package.json resides

Comment: Is it not possible to have both FE and BE in the same docker image/container?

Comment: On the DB - I do, but it's externally hosted - so my BE connects to it over IP. Is there a way to do this without docker-compose? It can't just be done with the docker file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66969885/run-front-end-and-backend-within-single-docker-container Here's how you can build the image with multi-stage build

Comment: You can compile the front-end to static files, and serve them from your back-end container; I'd consider that an intermediate-level Docker setup.  You can't(*) run two separate servers in the same container, run two separate containers for this setup.

Comment: @DavidMaze is it better to run two separate docker containers on the same ec2 device? They'll be able to connect to each other ok? I managed to get a docker container running locally with two servers running on it

Answer (score 0):

This is a docker file for the frontend(`client` in your case). You can make a `dockerfile` under your `client` folder and build the image with `docker build -t image-name:tag-name .`

```
# Pull the latest node image from dockerhub
FROM node:latest
# Create app directory 
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# Copy package.json and package-lock.json to the workdir
COPY package*.json ./ 
# Install the dependencies
RUN npm install
# Bundle app source
COPY . .
# Run the app in docker
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: See, I want the FE and BE in a single container. Is that possible? Also, what is the logic behind your WORKDIR in relation to the structure I've given above?